# Accessing parent class's original method after overriding it in subclass #Solved

Tags: java

Edit: I was still sleepy from getting up and just didn't pay atttention as to how I called the methods in the main class. Everything actually works, thanks

I have a Circle Class with a getArea Method

```
public class Circle {
    private double radius;

   public Circle(double radius){
       radius = (( radius < 0 )) ? 0 : radius;
       this.radius=radius;
   }

    public double getRadius() {
        return radius;
    }

    public double getArea() {
       return (radius*radius*Math.PI);
    }
}
```

Additionally, I have a Cylinder Class.

In the Cylinder Class, I would like to override the getArea method, while still being able to access the Circle Class's getArea method in order to calculate the volume.

```
public class Cylinder extends Circle{
    private double height;

    public Cylinder(double radius, double height){
        super(radius);
        height = (( height < 0 )) ? 0 : height;
        this.height=height;
    }

    public double getHeight() {
        return height;
    }

    public double getVolume() {
        return (super.getArea()*height);
    }

    @Override
    public double getArea() {
        return (2*Math.PI*getRadius()*height);
    }
}
```

Expected result:

Due to the 'super.' before the getArea method inside the getVolume method, the getVolume method would call the original getArea method (as if I had not overridden it)

Actual result:

It doesn't matter whether there is a 'super.' before the getArea method or not, the overridden method is always called, leading to a false volume calculation.

Is there a way to call the not overridden version of the getArea method after overriding it?

Comment: What makes you think the superclass's method is not being called? Try writing `System.out.println("Ka-ching!");` in the `Circle.getArea` method, and then call the `getVolume()` method on the subclass; if it prints `Ka-ching!` then you called the superclass's method.

Comment: [edit] your question and add the code where you create a `Cylinder` object and then call its `getVolume()` method.

Comment: I was still sleepy from getting up and just didn't pay atttention as to how I called the methods in the main class. Everything actually works, thanks